# Robot Framework API - getting test suite/subsuite results and test case results using one class

Tags: python, robotframework

I have one test suite with multiple subsuites. There are one or more test cases in each subsuite. For example:

```
TestSuite
  Subsuite-1
    TestCase-1
    TestCase-2
  Subsuite-2
    TestCase-1
  Subsuite-3
    TestCase-1
    TestCase-2
    TestCase-3
```

So far I've been using this code with separate classes for suite and test case results:

```
from robot.api import ExecutionResult, ResultVisitor


class GetRfSuiteResults(ResultVisitor):
    suite_results = {}

    def visit_suite(self, suite):
        self.suite_results[suite.name] = suite.status


class GetRfTestResults(ResultVisitor):
    test_results = {}

    def visit_test(self, test):
        self.test_results[test.parent,test.name] = test.status
```

As they both inherit the same `ResultVisitor` is it possible to get the results using one class like this?

```
from robot.api import ExecutionResult, ResultVisitor


class GetRfResults(ResultVisitor):
    suite_results = {}
    test_results = {}

    def visit_suite(self, suite):
        self.suite_results[suite.name] = suite.status

    def visit_test(self, test):
        self.test_results[test.parent,test.name] = test.status
```

I can't figure out how to access `visit_test` in this solution.

Comment: How and where do you "access" `visit_suite` and `visit_test` in first solution?

Comment: @akane You have to pass the `ResultVisitor` instance to the `visit` function of an `ExectutionResult` instance. Example: https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/master/autodoc/robot.result.html?highlight=ResultVisitor#example

Comment: Cool, I had no clue about these stuff. Appreciate you post the link and point in right direction, interesting reading, I have a lot to learn. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it mentions `SuiteVisitor` and not `ResultVisitor` I would venture with a guess that it behaves the same. From the [API doc](https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/master/autodoc/robot.model.html#visitor-algorithm):

> Visitors extending the SuiteVisitor can stop visiting at a certain
> level either by overriding suitable visit_x() method or by returning
> an explicit False from any start_x() method.

So if you override `visit_suite` it will stop visiting there.

If you would like to have one `ResultVisitor` that fetches the suite and test statuses as well, you could try something like this:

```py
class MyResultVisitor(ResultVisitor):

    def __init__(self):
        self.suite_results = {}
        self.test_results = {}

    def visit_suite(self, suite):
        self.suite_results[suite.name] = suite.status
        for test in suite.tests:
            self.test_results[test.parent,test.name] = test.status
            
        for suite in suite.suites:
            self.visit_suite(suite)
            
        return False
```

Visiting only the top suite, you could recursively visit all child suites and their tests as well.

Comment: Thanks Bence! The second solution works like a charm. I moved `self.suite_results[suite.name] = suite.status` to the second for loop to have only subsuites' results in `suite_results`, because the parent suite's result is not needed in my case.
I haven't tried the first one, because I don't know how to override `visit_suite` but most probably will figure this out soon.

Comment: @King This is one solution. The first part of the answer is about why `visit_suite` and `visit_test` do not work together. Overriding in this context means that you have a class, that inherits `ResultVisitor` and when you implement the `visit_suite` method, you are basically overriding the method with the same name from the base class.

Comment: Thanks again. I haven't read your answer carefully enough. Btw do you know why `suite_results` keys' types are `class 'str'` but `test_results` keys are `class 'robot.result.model.TestSuite'`? I use defaultdict for `test_results` and `test_results[key]` does not work because keys are not strings.

Comment: I solved it myself by adding `str()` in `self.test_results[str(test.parent)][test.name] = test.status` and `test_results[key]` works.